# How to make a color gradient mask?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, mask

I am wondering if it's somehow possible to create a more or less opposite gradient (maybe with less saturation) for all these Vectors on this background (I'm not ever sure if it's going to look good...).

Thats how it looks like now:
[image: Background with gradient and some objects on top]

The problem is, that the all the objects should have a consistent gradient

Comment: You might want to try to put your gradient in front of the other shapes and play with its blending mode.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's only the background that has a gradient. All the other objects are uniform in colour, and have no gradients whatsoever, just simple fills.  Not sure I can work out what you are trying to ask.

Comment: I agree with @BillyKerr -- Looks like the background is a gradient, then everything else uses a flat fill of the lighter gradient color.

Comment: Are you asking how to change that flat fill in the foreground objects to a gradient spanning them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the idea of having a reverse gradient as the fill is tried. The shapes are combined to a compound path and 180 degrees rotated gradient is applied. The gradient is global:

[image]

Not especially good! Very low contrast and shapes, which are side by side with no space, seem to be one.

Let's copy the original shapes onto the gradiented ones and reduce the transparency:

[image]

The opacity of the original shapes is 14%. That seems to be useful, but the contrast is still low if we want to have "nearly reverse gradient fill"

Another option is to make the gradients individual (=no compound path, the originals are removed from the top)

[image]

This helps the "be as one" problem and dosn't increase the colour range. But the contrast is still weak. Clearly seems to make the shapes to look out as curved.

The last test is to have a three stop gradient, brightest in the middle and a little extended to the dark end

[image]

This seem to be a bunch of cylinders. Maybe unusable. I would continue to develop version 2.

NOTE if you have strokes, outlining them make colorings faster to do.

ADDENDUM: An improved version of 2 - this is for making more contrast, not to reduce it:

[image]

Here on the top there are the original shapes, but they have the blending mode = Hard light. Underlying there is a grey gradient, from about 75% white to black. Starting from full white washes the colors too much. The gradient fills a compound of the original shapes.